# Kill AsyncTask on notification tap

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-asynctask

I'd need a little help, I have no idea how to do this:

There's a notification that gets updated by a background AsyncTask, what I want to do is cancel/stop the AsyncTask completely when I tap on the notification (What it does now is open another instance of the application, without stopping the old AsyncTask).

I want to point out that right after I start the background AsyncTask, I close the UI using

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(i);
```

I'm not sure that's the best way to do remove the UI while keeping the AsyncTask running, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself a workaround. Instead of an AsyncTask I ran a Service, which can easily be stopped with a stopService. Then, I created a new activity with just stopService, changed the intent of the notification to that context, and done.